# How to find what ring a process is running on in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, 64bit, privileges

How can I find out which protection ring a given process is running in, and if possible can I produce a list of running processes with their respective rings? This thread gives some insight into what rings are utilised on an x86 processor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717016/what-are-ring-0-and-ring-3-in-the-context-of-operating-systems

I would like to know how to find out what protection ring level processes are running in myself, not be given a description of what rings processes *will* be running in (although you can include it if you want).

Comment: if there's a creepy critter in the shadows muttering about a "precious", it's the Tolkien ring.

Comment: @quixotic not to be confused with the token ring ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On *x86*, the current privilege level is [determined by the bottom two bits](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/cpu-rings-privilege-and-protection/) of the code segment selector, *i.e.* the value stored in the CS register. So "all" you need to do to determine the current privilege level of a process is look at the value of its CS register.

You can do that quite easily for your own program (assuming 64-bit *x86*):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    uint64_t rcs = 0;
    asm ("mov %%cs, %0" : "=r" (rcs));
    printf("%d\n", (int) (rcs & 3));
    return 0;
}
```

For other processes, you'd have to attach to them using something like `ptrace`, and examine their registers. You can do this manually using `gdb`: identify a process, attach to it (if you're allowed to) using `gdb --pid ...`, then issue the `gdb` command `info registers cs` to see the current value of CS, and extract the value of the least-significant two bits.

On Linux on *x86* you'll quickly see that the current privilege level is always 3: user processes always run in ring 3, except when they’re in system calls (which run in ring 0) — but you won’t be able to see them in ring 0 externally, except by tracing kernel code using `ftrace` for example.

Comment: Every normal (non-kernel thread) process runs in both ring 3 and ring 0. When a process performs a system call, it switches from ring 3 to ring 0. You can't categorize processes based on which ring they are running in, unless you are interested in which ring they are running in at a particular moment in time.

Comment: @Johan thanks, you’re right, I meant that the OP would only ever see a ring 3 CPL using the techniques mentioned in the answer. Hopefully the updated version is more accurate.